# Extracting JSON data from the request in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've started a new website with a node server to get more familiar with node.js, and I'm posting data to the server, but I can't figure out how to read the JSON data in the request:

Client request:

```
 function addSymptom(name) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/addSymptom',
            data: {
                symName: name
            },
            success: function (data) {
                listSymptoms();
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    }
```

Server handler:

```
     app.post('/addSymptom', function (req, res) {

        var newSymptom = req.body;
        console.log(newSymptom); // undefined :(

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            result: 'success'
        }));
     });
```

Why is the request.body undefined? Is there a different way I'm supposed to be reading the 'symName' field in the request body?

Comment: What HTTP library are you using on the server? Express?

Comment: Yes, I'm using express. There's a library called body-parser as well but I'm not sure how to use it, or if it's even possible with the req.body being null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

be sure to add on the node.js the bodyParser module..

If you're using Express 3.x / 4.x you just need to make sure you have the bodyParser included:

1. Express 3.x

   ```
   app.use(express.bodyParser({limit : '50mb'}));
   ```
2. Express 4.x

in your package file:

```
"body-parser": "~1.0.0",
```

or alternatively run npm-install body-parser

then in your node.js server:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create our app
var app = express();

// instruct the app to use the `bodyParser()` middleware for all routes
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Link to an example:
http://code.runnable.com/U0sU598vXio2uD-1/example-reading-form-input-with-express-4-0-and-body-parser-for-node-js
 3. Without express

If for some reason you've decide not to use express, you'll prob need to bind to the the data handler of the socket to read the data.

Here is an article on the matter: 
http://blog.frankgrimm.net/2010/11/howto-access-http-message-body-post-data-in-node-js/

Comment: I've had to add body-parser seperately as it's not longer bundled with express. How do I implement it?

Comment: @drminnaar look at express 4.x, as if it's not bundles you'll need to include the body-parser component.

Comment: Ok, I've got it up and running, it seems to have generated the body, but it's giving me an exception for invalid json. Considering the json I'm sending from the client, does it look badly formatted to you? It'd be nice to see the object structure of the req.body...

Comment: I have no idea, I do not see the JSON you've sent, I'd suggest you use a JSON validator to make sure your JSON is valid before you send it: http://jsonlint.com/ (can you also please accept the answer) ?